# Get DOM from a string

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom

Given a String which contains HTML for an entire page, I want only the innerHTML of the body. Rather than parse the HTML myself, it seems easier if I could make an element from the String, and then just get the body directly.

I found some things related, but that I couldn't get to work (I can't find the question anymore).

```
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    var ret = xmlhttp.responseText + "";

    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        alert(ret);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://url.php", false);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Right now I have this ajax request, but I need only the body from the return.

I tried `document.createElement(ret).body` and `new Element(ret).body` but they didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4):

```
var helper = document.createElement("html");
helper.innerHTML = ret;         
body = helper.querySelector("body"); //Or getElementsByTagName("body")[0]
```

Comment: `ret.body` or `helper.body`?

Comment: I'm getting an error on `helper.innerHTML = ret;`. "Could not set the innerHTML property. Invalid target element for this operation."

Comment: @Cruncher instead of using `html` try using another element, maybe just `x` or something

Comment: That removed the error, but `alert(helper.body)` gives me undefined, also `alert(helper.getElementsByTagName("body")[0])` gives me undefined, but `helper.getElementsByTagName("body")` gives me [object], but I can't use any dom functions on them.

Comment: @Cruncher http://jsfiddle.net/DHzcg/ -- seems to be working; take a look and see if it helps you

Comment: This appears to be an IE problem. The fiddle works fine in chrome. Do you know if there's a way to get this to work in IE?

Comment: @helloworld that requires me to run another php file, and make another ajax request. Surely there has to be a front end way. I would rather send an ajax request to my java server, have that send a get to the php that I need to parse, parse it in java, and return the body from the ajax call

Answer (score -1):

You could use  [simple_html_dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to do this, and get the HTML of the entire page using PHP, and then get only the contents of the body, like this

```
$html=file_get_html("url.php");
$body=$html->find("body");
$echo $body->plaintext
```